# I cannot install the github laroute package in laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I hope you will not laugh at me for asking something so basic, but I am honest, I am totally new working in laravel and I am actually locked with the installation of a package of github,

**I want to install the laroute package to work the routing in javascript same as in laravel**

[aaronlord/laroute: Generate Laravel route URLs from JavaScript.](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute)

I followed the instructions to install the package in my laravel project but when I execute the command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Lord\Laroute\LarouteServiceProvider'
```

I get the following error:

```
Php fatal error class 'Lord \ Laroute \ LarouteServiceProvider' not found in ...
```

I do not know if I should replace the word 'Lord' with another word, and I also do not know in which directory put the files I downloaded of github, please help me,

**What do I have to do to install it?
In what folder do I put the github files?**

I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I already found an answer,
Composer uses packages from the repository [Packagist](https://packagist.org) . I searched for the package name of github in this case 'laroute' and there I came up with a simple solution, run the following command in the console

```
Composer require lord / laroute...
```

and ready! Composer did everything!